# Unable to add Xcode proj library in the running Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am working on IOS app with react-native teachnology. I was trying to use react-native-store-photos-album project. The automatic linking is not working. So, when I trued to do it manually, I was unable to select the react-native-store-photos-album.xcodeproj file in the explorer. See the screenshot.

Questions: How to use this library? Is it compatibility issue?

```
Using: 
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.4",
    "react-native-store-photos-album": "github:francisco-sanchez-molina/react-native-store-photos-album",
```

Xcode version: 10

Comment: Isn’t that because it is already added. Looking at your screen shot it appears to be there on the left hand side.

Comment: Are you talking about 3rd last?

Comment: Yes. It appears to have the lettering.

Answer (score 0):

So, if the project is already present then it will not get selected. Thanks @andrew